# Conectar a ORACLE 32 bits desde python 64 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle-12c

tengo un pregunta, mi máquina es de 64 bits y necesito conectarme a ORACLE-12 de 32 bit. Mi código es:

```
oracle_path = "C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2"
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=oracle_path)
```

y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2/oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

En la URL no soy capaz de ver la solución. Cómo puedo indicar que mi ORACLE es de 32 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es la base de datos Oracle, ya que esta provee un servicio al que se pueden conectar distintos clientes, no importa la arquitectura en que se esté ejecutando (x32, x64, ia64...). El problema está en el controlador para conectarse, o sea, el Oracle InstantClient.

[Descarga Oracle InstantClient](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) adecuado para tu arquitectura de Python. Si es Python x64, entonces InstantClient x64.

Otra cosa, el desarrollo de cx_Oracle [está descontinuado](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/628) y está disponible hasta Python 3.10.
Para python 3.7 o superior (incluyendo la actual 3.11) usa [oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html), en conjunto con Oracle InstantClient respectivo.

Comment: Entonces el controlador InstantClient sí que puede ser x64 y operar con una BBDD de 32 bits, cierto? Muchas gracias por tu aportación!!!